# Editing a npm library and seeing changes live with hot reloading?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am working on a React.js website that uses webpack and some shared code in a module to which I also have the source code. I'd like to make some tweaks to the shared library but currently it's installed from npm via a node_module. How can I set up my development environment to be able to work on the shared module but still be able to see my changes to the module live with hot reloading?

Answer (score 4):

Use a local dependency, pointing to the local copy of your package:

```
{   
    "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo"
}
```

Then build `foo` in watch mode.

The main app will recognize that something has changed and will hot-reload the relevant parts.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, ../foo would be the relative path to the root of the module directory (i.e. the one containing package.json)? So this module will end up *not* being installed in node_modules ever, but rather just the parent directory or whatever that file: link points to?

Comment: Exactly. Technically, it will appear under `node_modules`, but this is merely a symlink.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to build in watch mode, you can use npm-watch. This tutorial helped me: https://medium.com/how-to-react/use-npm-watch-to-auto-build-your-reactjs-app-6ed0e5d6cb00

Comment: So building a project in watch mode means installing and using the 3rd party `npm-watch` tool? Very unclear from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Here is a more descriptive answer of how to use `yarn link`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48688156/2748017

---

It looks like there is a built in solution to handle this with yarn.

**docs:** https://yarnpkg.com/cli/link

```
$> yarn link <destination>
```

I believe [npm might handle this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link), too, just with a bit more lifting.

As far as hot reloading, I think that more-so depends on the app consuming the local dependency, but npm-watch seems like a decent solution.