# Yarn local packages dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have the following folder structure:

```
~ (user home folder)
 - api
    ...
    - package.json
 - lib
    - libA
      ...
      package.json
    - libB
      ...
      package.json
```

In `libA/package.json` I have the following local dependency

```
"dependencies": {
    "libB": "../libB",
  },
```

So libA depends on libB.

Now I want inside `api` project to add as local package `libA`. I execute `cd api && yarn add ../lib/libA` and I get the following error`/Users/a_user/libB doesn't exist`. I understand that yarn sees as current director `~/api` so when is reading the dependency of `libA` it sees `../libB` and translate it as `~/libB` and not as `~/lib/libB`

Is there anyway to achieve it without absolute paths ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, there is, using [yarn link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/). Yarn link allows you to create symlinks to local projects.

Go to the folder `libB` and run:

```
yarn link
```

Then go to the folder `libA` and run:

```
yarn link libB
```

**NOTE**: that `libB` must be the name on the `package.json` inside the `libB` folder

Then you can require your `libB` code as usual:

```
const libB = require('libB')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One thing I do not understand. Should I have inside dependencies of libA the libB or the liking is enough ?

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I get `Error: Cannot find module 'libB'` when I execute `yarn install` inside api folder

Comment: You need to run `yarn link libB` inside the API folder

Comment: API uses `libA` and `libA` uses `libB`. I `yarn link` inside `libB`, then `yarn link libB` inside `libA`. Then inside `api` I used `yarn add ../lib/A`. That failed. I had to `yarn add libB` inside `libA` despite the use of `yarn link libB` to make it work

Comment: So you also need to do the `yarn link`inside libA and then run `yarn link libA` inside the API

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a version of this answer for yarn 2? New yarn doesn't execute yarn link without additional parameters.

Comment: @DavidMin yarn2 you only need to run `yarn link path/to/lib/b` inside the libA folder https://yarnpkg.com/cli/link

Comment: @FabioAntunes I did do that, but after it adds a 'resolution' field in my `package.json`, what do I do next? It still says module not found when I try to import.

Comment: @DavidMin Ask a new question and tag it with yarnpkg-v2

Comment: @FabioAntunes way ahead of you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68734110/yarn-2-berry-modern-pnp-adding-local-package-yarn-link

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is way much simpler than I expected...

Answer (score 0):

The package where I created the link from used npm, where-as the second package that was consuming the first one used yarn.

In my case, I had to create as well as consume the link using npm link rather than yarn link as that is what the first package that I wanted to consume used.