# npm / yarn package sharing for local projects?

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I have a Typescript project using yarn and I want to share packages with another project.

Coming from Java / Maven, it seems like this should be easy but with npm/yarn it's not straight forward.

I tried:

1. [yarn link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686053/yarn-local-packages-dependencies) (caused more problems than solutions)
2. relative path linking:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
    "@myGroup/myProject": "./path/to/other/project", 
     ...
   }
   ```
3. [yalc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yalc)

but none worked for me.

What is a simple way to share packages between local projects?

Answer (score 0):

1. In your main project's package.json, add a 'workspaces' section and the dependency reference::

   ```
   "workspaces": [                                                                 
    "packages/*"                                                                
   ], 
   "dependencies": {
    "@myGroup/myProject": "1.0.0", 
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Now **symlink** to the project you want to share:

   `ln -s /path/to/other/project/packages packages/`

   Where "/path/to/other/project/packages" contains a package.json with:

   ```js
    {                                                                                   
       "name": "@myGroup/myProject",                                                                                                                                   
       "version": "1.0.0",
        ...
    }
   ```

This will create a *symbolic link* in your current packages/ subfolder to the project you're linking to.

This is essentially the same as what `yarn link` does but in a much more straight forward way.

Now a `yarn install` and should find the local shared package.

Comment: This is also not a cross platform solution.

Comment: @pascalpuetz I searched every answer on SO and googled this to death and didn't find this answer. The point is that now there's an answer available for others.

Comment: @AluanHaddad true, not cross platform. macOs/Linux.