# Adding local dependency in a Typescript project doesn't work when it works in JS

Tags: typescript, webpack, yarnpkg, ts-loader, yarnpkg-v2

I have been able to import a local package into a project by running `yarn link ../path`, which adds a `resolution` field to the `package.json` to tell the bundler where to find a package, basically giving it an alias.

Weird thing is that while this works when the file I'm doing the importing from is `.jsx`, not changing anything else, if I'm importing from `.tsx`, the module is not found.

So the culprit could be ts-loader, Typescript (how it treats imports), webpack, or yarn. I don't know if this is because I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug.

So the folder structure might be:

```
--ProjectMain
  ----/src
  ------index.jsx
  ----package.json

--ProjectToImport
  ----/src
  ------index.js
  ----package.json
```

I have the following in `webpack.config.js` in ProjectMain

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /\.yarn/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
          },
        },
        exclude: /\.yarn/
      }
    ],
  },
```

ProjectToImport's `index.js` looks like

```
export function SharedLibTest(a){
  console.log(a)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the whole thing was because in my `ProjectToImport/package.json`, I used `"main": "/src/index.js"`, instead of `"main": "src/index.js"`

I don't know why this makes a difference just because I'm using TS, may the wise among you enlighten me.

Comment: This literally saved me hours of debugging.

Thanks